# droplist only with specific file with php

Tags: php, file

I'm currently making a droplist but in the droplist let's say I only want to include only .txt extension files so any other extensions like .php .jpg or any other extensions will not be in in the droplist.  How can I do that as simple as possible?

Another question is I want to make a warning IF the folder does not have any .txt extension files an error message will show.  So even if there are other .jpg .php or any other files inside as long as there's no .txt file in the folder a warning will show.

Anyone able to give me a hand?

This is what I have done but it only shows a drop-list with no .txt at the end but it will still show other random files in the drop-list though.

```
if(!(is_dir("./aaa")))
{
    die("Must create a folder first, sorry");
}

    $lists = scandir("./aaa");

    echo "<form action=\"./page2.php\" method=\"get\">";
    echo "<select>";

    foreach($lists as $list)
    {
    if(($list == ".") || ($list == ".."))
        {
        continue;
        }
    echo "<option value=\"";
    echo basename($list,".txt");
    echo "\">";
    echo basename($list,".txt");
    echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</form>";
```

---

editted added the substr with $hasTxt

```
<?php
if(!(is_dir("./aaa")))
{
    die("Must create a <strong>aaa</strong> folder first, sorry");
}
echo "<form action=\"./page2.php\" method=\"get\">";
echo "<select name=\"aaa\">";
    $aaa_files = scandir("./aaa"); 
$hastxt = false; 
foreach($aaa_files as $file_list) 
{
    if(($file_list == ".") || ($file_list == ".."))
    {
    continue;
    }
    if(strlen($file_list)>4 && strtolower(substr($file_list, -4))!='.txt')
    {
    continue;
    }
    else 
    {
    $hastxt = true; 
    echo "<option value=\"";
    echo basename($file_list,".txt");  
    echo "\">";
    echo basename($file_list,".txt");
    echo "</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br/><input type=\"submit\">";
echo "</form>";

if($hastxt == false) 
{
    echo "Must create text files first, sorry";
    die();
}
?>
```

---

This is what happens for the script that I have now if the folder does not have any txt files.

[image]

---

This is what I actually want if there's no txt file but of course without the arrow

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, just like you continue on directories . and .., you can continue on non-text files:

```
if(strlen($list)>4 && strtolower(substr($list, -4))!='.txt') continue;
```

For the warning part, put a flag before the foreach

```
$hasTxt = false;
```

And set it to true whenever you get input you don't ignore (ie. after the if(unwanted) continue;)

```
$hasTxt = true;
```

Finally, after the foreach check the value of $hasTxt and use it as you prefer.

Comment: ah....right....I do understand those but I wonder what if someone named the file TxT or TXT because I used strtolower as you said and I changed one of the file to .TXT that file won't show though.  Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Also the $hasTxt worked fine thanks thanks but I realized if I do that and let's say eh....my dropbox will just be empty then with the false it'll show let's say a message "no txt" is there a way that in the same page if there's no .txt file in the folder the whole page will just say "no txt" instead of showing the dropbox too?

Comment: @user1850712, you're right about 'no txt', I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: As for TxT and TXT, strtolower() is there precisely to avoid the very problem you have, so I can think about two explanations: 1) you accidentally put a space after the extension (can happen on graphic interfaces and even on the command line), or 2) you have an input method for a language written in Cyrillic, and you typed the Cyrillic equivalent of a Latin character in the extension (very unlikely though, but that's used in some kind of hacks)

Comment: that's weird because that's what I thought the strtolower() is for too but still didn't work properly though.  is it possible to take another peek for me?

Comment: somehow if let's say I change the asdf.txt into asdf.TXT then in the droplist it'll show asdf.TXT instead of asdf.  Also the $hasTxt == false I can only add it to the bottom of the script. I tried putting it somewhere else or do a foreach loop first before the droplist so if $hasTxt is false then the whole page will show the error message.  But seems like I can only put it at the bottom of the script which will show the droplist with nothing in it then with the no text error.  What did I miss?

Comment: Unless you're sure your script will always run on a Windows server, most likely you want asdf.TXT to appear like that. In that case you can put this line at the beginning of the foreach: $list = strtolower($list);
As for the place where my suggestions should go, your edited question has it correctly

Comment: ah! Thanks....I'm so stupid...putting strtolower() inside if doesn't changing the variable...always miss the small mistakes......by the way, what's the difference from running on windows server and linux? I'm totally new with php thing.  And as for the "no txt" Let me add an image file up....

Comment: I added image to how this script runs if there's no txt file in the folder...but that's not what I want though.  What I want is how the second image shows.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Win and Lin have many differences, but the reason for my comment was that in Windows, filenames are case-insensitive: asdf and AsDF are the same, whereas in Linux they are different.

Comment: As for the second thing, instead of echoing all the <select> code as you get the data, you're better off putting it on a text variable. Then after the foreach you can decide wether to print it out or not

Comment: Besides, considering your question is already answered, would you mind choosing my answer as the right one? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ^_^ just chose the answer to be the right one.  Even though I'm still confused about the echoing all the <select> code you are talking about :P

Comment: Thank you! What I mean is this: http://pastebin.com/C0L35WrS
Hope it's more clear now!

Comment: trying to understand it hehe....because I'm a bit confused at the .= operator...I looked it up at php.net but not sure how it's used and how it works in this situation....sorry I'm totally new to php.  Anyways thanks again ^_^ I'll try to digest first these two days....if I'm still confused I'll post another thread.  Thanks again ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's substr() function to test the filenames:

```
if(substr($filename, -3) == 'txt') {
  // show file
}
```

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this , Hope it will work you

```
<?php
    if(!(is_dir("./aaa")))
    {
        die("Must create a folder first, sorry");
    }

    $lists = scandir("./aaa");
    $i =0;
    foreach($lists as $list)
    {
        if (strstr($list, '.txt')) {
        $i++;
        }
    }
    if($i == 0){
        die("the folder does not have any .txt extension files");
    }

    echo "<form action=\"./page2.php\" method=\"get\">";
    echo "<select>";

    foreach($lists as $list)
    {
        if (strstr($list, '.txt')) {
            echo "<option value=\"".substr($list,0, -4)."\">".substr($list, 0,-4)."    </option>";
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</form>";
?>
```